# Java stream api using reference of original object within chain

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to create a Map from a list, whereas value of Map would be a result of some transformation, this is how my code looks like.

```
empIdList.stream()
         .map(id-> getDepartment(id))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(id, department:String -> department)
```

in this above example I am looking to use `id` as key and `department` as value. can you please help me achieving my expected results.

Answer (score 6):

You could avoid the `map` function and directly invoke `collect`

```java
empIdList.stream()    
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getDepartment);
```

If the list does not have unique ids, then it would result in an `IllegalStateException` so:

1. Either pass a `Set` of ids instead of a `List` if possible.
2. OR use `distinct()` in between `stream()` and `collect()`.
3. OR provide a dummy merging function as the third argument to `toMap`: `Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getDepartment, (a,b) -> a)`

Comment: To be on the safe side, make sure that the list does not contain duplicate ids by using `distinct()` or by providing a merging function when collecting to map.

Comment: Manish, as @Eritrean pointed out, take care of the possibility of receiving a non-unique id list. I have updated the answer with the relevant info.